# Data is not coming into form from database

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to make a insert update delete grid but when I click on update link data is not coming into form. Here is my code.

```
<?php
public function editAction() {

    $form = new Application_Form_user();
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isvalid($formData)) {
            $client = new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();
            $firstname = $form->getvalue('firstname');
            $lastname = $form->getvalue('lastname');
            $email = $form->getvalue('email');
            $client->updateclient($id, $firstname, $lastname, $email);
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        } else {
            $this->populate($formData);
        }
    } else {

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getparam('id');
        if ($id > 0) {

            $client = new Application_Model_DbTable_Client();
            $clients = $client->getClient($id);

            $this->populate($clients);
        }
    }
}
```

my model code :-

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Client extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'client';

    public function getClient($id) {
        global $db;
        $query = $db->select()->from('client');
        if ($id > 0) {
            $query->where('Id=?', $id);
        }
        $data = $db->fetchAll($query);
        return $data;
    }

    public function addClient() {
        print_r($data);
        die;
        $data = array('fisrtname' => 'firstname',
            'lastname' => 'lastname',
            'email' => 'email');
        $this->insert($data);
    }

    public function updateClient() {
        $data = array('fisrtname' => 'firstname',
            'lastname' => 'lastname',
            'email' => 'email');
        $this->update($data, 'Id=' . $id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are you not catching any arguments in model ??

How will it get values if you are not catching them !!

use this,

```
 public function updateclient($id, $firstname, $lastname, $email) {
        $data = array('fisrtname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'email' => $email);
        $this->update($data, 'Id=' . $id);
    }
```

also for populating data into form use,

`$form->populate` not `$this->populate`..